# Wordpress - wp_insert_post with resized post thumbnail

Tags: image, wordpress, post, thumbnails, web-crawler

I will crawl some data from an XML file and I have all the information I need including the image URL.

There is a function in Wordpress called wp_insert_post which is used to create posts programmically. So far, so good. Simple to use:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

What I also need is:

- Add an image attached to the post thumbnail by its image URL (for example http://www.test.com/my-image.jpg)
- Resize it on upload with Wordpress built in functions (for example max 300 x 300, like medium thumbnail settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function for that.

```
media_sideload_image($url,$post_id,$description);
```

There is a post about this [here.](http://wordpresskillertips.blogspot.com/2011/04/inserting-post-image-programmatically.html)

And in the theme you can use this function for getting the thumb in required size

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

[Read more at codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Default thumbnail sizes also can be changed, [see this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size).